# Chinese character becomes corrupted when passed to Excel from javascript

Tags: javascript, excel, encoding, utf-8, excel-2013

```js
function View_ParamReport() {
   var xmlPathName = inputPath.innerText;
   //Based on the input selcted it selectes the particular xslt code and generates the xml output
   var xml = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0");
   xml.async=false;
   xml.load(xmlPathName);
   var xsl = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.FreeThreadedDOMDocument.6.0");
   xsl.setProperty("AllowDocumentFunction", true); 
   xsl.async=false;
   var xslTemp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XSLTemplate.6.0");
   xslTemp.stylesheet  = xsl;

   var xslProc = xslTemp.createProcessor();
   xslProc.input = xml;                
   try {
       xslProc.transform;
       var report2= xslProc.output; 
       var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
       var filePath = "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\" + orderNumber + ".xls";        
       var s = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath, true);       
       s.WriteLine(report2);
       //If I pass some chinese  character in the  report2 it is                  //getting corrupted.
       //Eg:s.WriteLine("订单编号"); gives ???? in the excel 
       s.Close();
       window.open(filePath);
   } catch(e) {
            
   }

}
```

I am trying to pass the xsl output to Excel using javascript. It works fine when the output is English. However when it is a mix of English and Chinese it correctly shows the English letters but the Chinese characters becomes corrupted string. I am using Excel 2013. How can I fix this?

Comment: Please show at least the first lines XML of your `xmlPathName`. Since your `xsl` seems to be an empty XSL, `xslProc.transform;` will not transforming something but only passing the XML of your `xmlPathName` to your `report2`.

Comment: Added the code as asked. :)

Comment: You are kidding me. I had asked for the XML, the `xml.load(xmlPathName);` will load, and you tell me that the `xmlPathName` comes from `inputPath.innerText`. What shall I do withn this information? I cannot open the file behind `xmlPathName = inputPath.innerText`. So no help possible, at least not from me.

Comment: Btw.: The "Unicode" which the [FileSystemObject.CreateTextFile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5t9b5c0c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) is using is **not** `UTF-8` but `UTF-16LE`.

Comment: The XML is not posing an issue. When I am passing a chinese character in the xml , I am able to open Excel. However in place of the chineese character I am seeing corrrupted code. 

I have given the example.
Instead of  s.WriteLine(report2); if i write s.WriteLine("订单编号");
I get  corrupted code.

Comment: I got the answer.
 I had to change one line only
**var s = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath, true); ** 
**var s = fso.CreateTextFile(filePath, true,true);** 

Thank you @Axel. You helped to stumble upon it . :)

Comment: Glad it works now. I had not seen that you only had set `overwrite` true and not `unicode`. Thought it is a `UTF-8` vs. `UTF-16LE` issue. Thats why the question about the lirst lines from the source XML, possible containing the XML declaration.